# Recuperar objectos de un modelo en django

Tags: django

Tengo los siguientes modelos relacionados.

```
class Puesto(models.Model):
nombre_depto = models.CharField(max_length=30)
clave_depto = models.CharField(max_length=30)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Persona(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=30)
usr_clave = models.CharField(max_length=12)
puestos = models.ForeignKey(Puesto, blank=True, null=True)
```

Y estoy tratando de devolver los empleados que pertencen a cada uno de los puestos que se tienen registrados y obtner algo asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado investigando sobre como recuperar los objetos relacionados entre si y poderlos mostrar en otros templates pero hasta el momento no he encontrado algo que me sea de utilidad para resolver este problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito la respuesta de acuerdo a tu comentario y procura ser mas especifico en lo que preguntas, y en lo posible coloca el codigo de lo que has intentado hacer, para que facilite las respuestas.

Yo lo haria asi, teniendo en cueta que dices que el listado de los puesto ya esta:

1. Agrega ellink al template donde muestres los puestos:

**Template de los puestos**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Puesto</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for puesto in puestos %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'puestoPersonas' puesto.id %}">{{ puesto.nombre_depto }}</a></td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

2. Crea la url para la vista donde se mostraran las personas filtradas por puestos:

**url.py**

```
url(r'^puestoPersonas/(?P<id_puesto>\d+)/$', puestosPersonas, name='puestoPersonas'),
```

3. Agrega esta Vista:

**Views.py**

```
def puestoPersonas(request, id_puesto):    
    personas = Persona.objects.distinct().filter(puestos=id_puesto)
    return render(request,'comosellame.html',{ 'personas':personas })
```

4. Pinta los datos:

**template**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmpleadoId</td>
            <th>Nombres</td>
            <th>Apellidos</td>
            <th>Puesto</td>
            <th>Puesto ID</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for persona in personas %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ persona.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.apellidos }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.puestos.nombre_depto }}</td>
                <td>{{ persona.puestos.id }}</td>
            </tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

De esta forma obtienes lo que **Entendi** que estas buscando

Comment: Buen día jhon y muchas gracias por responder. El problema es que quiero listar los **puestos** y al darle click a un boton o link, este te lleve a otro template que te muestre los empleados que pertenecen a ese puesto.

El listado de los puestos ya esta, pero no he podido encontrar la forma de recuperar las **personas** que pertenecen al puesto seleccionado y devolverlas a un template.

Comment: @Ismael Caslop Editada la respuesta

Comment: @john1946 muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, me funciono a la perfección, y si, trataré de ser un poco mas especifico en mis proximas preguntas.
De verdad de lo agradezco mucho.